# How are locks differenciated in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking, ipc, mutex

Let's say that you have two lists created with manager.list(), and two locks created with manager.Lock(). How do you assign each lock to each list?
I was doing like

```
lock1 = manager.Lock()
lock2 = manager.Lock()
list1 = manager.list()
list2 = manager.list()
```

and when I wanted to write/read from the list

```
lock1.acquire()
list1.pop(0)
lock1.release()

lock2.acquire()
list2.pop(0)
lock2.released()
```

Today I realized that there's nothing that associates lock1 to list1.
Am I misunderstanding these functions?

Comment: There's nothing that automatically associates locks with data, it's the application's responsibility to know which lock goes with each list.

Comment: You should create a custom class containing `list` & `lock`. Ensure that all methods in the class that require the lock, acquire it before manipulating the list. `register` that class with the manager & use it that way.

Comment: @Barmar but if I use lock1.acquire() how can I say that this is about list1 and not list2?

Comment: @NicoliHc that may be a misconception - locks are just about _themselves_, and are a gateway which you can arbitrarily use! You can hint as to what they're for by naming them, using some custom class, etc. . Additionally, whenever you want a synchronized list, consider if you can use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)

Comment: With a comment: `# lock1 is mutex for list1`

Comment: @rdas I understand what you are saying but I still can't see how this would separate each lock to each list. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Barmar, I know the difference between the locks, I want to know how they differentiate between them..

Comment: @ti7 But if I have two lists, one lock will block both lists?

Comment: Yes, exactly - or rather one lock synchronizes access, and can be used to block acquisition of any number of resources

Comment: There's nothing that "makes a lock, lock down a list" . By putting some code between `lock.acquire()` & `lock.realease()` you merely make that code executable by only one thread/process at a time. There is nothing special about that code, it can use a list, it can make an API call, it can do anything. That's up to the application.

Comment: @ti7 So regardless of the number of lists I will only need one lock?

Comment: @NicoliHc If you use the same lock for all lists, then it means that only one thread can access any of the lists at a time. This will reduce the effectiveness of multithreading.

Comment: @Barmar, this is my goal at the moment..

Comment: Then do that. As you said, there's nothing that associates a lock with a specific list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR yes, and this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

If you create a `multiprocessing.Manager()` and use its methods to create container primitives (`.list` and `.dict`), they will already be synchronized and you don't need to deal with the synchronization primitives yourself

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, freeze_support

def my_function(d, lst):
    lst.append([x**2 for x in d.values()])

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:  # context-managed SyncManager
        normal_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
        managed_synchronized_dict = manager.dict(normal_dict)
        managed_synchronized_list = manager.list()  # used to store results
        p = Process(
            target=my_function,
            args=(managed_synchronized_dict, managed_synchronized_list)
        )
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print(managed_synchronized_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

```sh
% python3 ./test_so_66603485.py
[[1, 4]]
```

[multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array), is also synchronized

BEWARE: [proxy objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) are not directly comparable to their Python collection equivalents

> **Note:** The proxy types in multiprocessing do nothing to support comparisons by value. So, for instance, we have:
>
> ```py
> >>> manager.list([1,2,3]) == [1,2,3]
> False
> ```
>
> One should just use a copy of the referent instead when making comparisons.

---

Some confusion might come from the section of the multiprocessing docs on [Synchronization Primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives), which implies that one should use a Manager to create synchronization primitives, when really the Manager can already do the synchronization for you

> #### Synchronization primitives
>
> Generally synchronization primitives are not as necessary in a multiprocess program as they are in a multithreaded program. See the documentation for [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module.
>
> Note that one can also create synchronization primitives by using a manager object – see [Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers).

If you use simply `multiprocessing.Manager()`, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), it

> Returns a started [SyncManager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) object which can be used for sharing objects between processes. The returned manager object corresponds to a spawned child process and has methods which will create shared objects and return corresponding proxies.

From the [SyncManager section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager)

> Its methods create and return Proxy Objects for a number of commonly used data types to be synchronized across processes. This notably includes shared lists and dictionaries.

This means that you probably have most of what you want already

- manager object with methods for building managed types
- synchronization via [Proxy Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-proxy-objects)

---

Finally, to sum up the thread from comments specifically about instances of Lock objects

- there's no inherent way to tell that some named lock is for anything in particular other than meta-information such as its name, comment(s), documentation ..conversely, they're free to be used for whatever synchronization needs you may have
- some useful class/container can be made to manage both the lock and whatever it should be synchronizing -- a normal `multiprocessing.Manager` (`SyncManager`)'s `.list` and `.dict` do this, and a variety of other useful constructs exist, such as [Pipe and Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)
- one lock can be used to synchronize any number of actions, but having more locks can be a valuable trade-off as they are potentially unnecessarily blocking access to resources
- [a variety of synchronization primitives also exist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives) for different purposes

```py
value = my_queue.get()  # already synchronized

if not my_lock1.acquire(timeout=5):  # False if cannot acquire
    raise CustomException("failed to acquire my_lock1 after 5 seconds")
try:
    with my_lock2():    # blocks until acquired
        some_shared_mutable = some_container_of_mutables[-1]
        some_shared_mutable = some_object_with_mutables.get()
        if foo(value, some_shared_mutable):
            action1(value, some_shared_mutable)
            action2(value, some_other_shared_mutable)
finally:
    lock2.release()
```